# Twitter bootstrap class navbar-collapse erases the <ul>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to learn Bootstrap and I am currently coding the navbar of my new website. But everytime I put a div with nav-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse collapse classes the links in the UL of the navbar just dissapear. Here is the code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">

           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">FUTURE LOGO</a> 

           <div class="nav-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                 <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home white"></span> Domu</a></li>

                 <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>

                 <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Section<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Subsection</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Subsection</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Subsection</a></li>

                      <li class="divider"></li>

                      <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown-header</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Subsection</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Subsection</a></li>
                    </ul><!-- End dropdown-menu-->
                 </li><!-- End dropdown-->
              </ul><!--End nav-->
           </div><!-- End navbar-collapse-->
        </div> <!-- End container-->
    </div> <!-- End navbar-->
```

Comment: Does it appear when you make your browser window very narrow?

Comment: No, It appears even with the wide browser window..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just figured it out. In the new version of the bootstrap, there is nothing like nav-collapse but It is changed to navbar-collapse.

Comment: don't worry, that's my next move.

Answer (score -1):

Include java script file which are in ./js folder.

Comment: I have included the bootstrap.min.js file, that's not It.